# Do logger always read debug even if level is set to info and does it have any significant impact?

Tags: java, logging

As the title say.
If I have a

```
LOGGER.debug(model.toString())
```

and I set the logging level to INFO, will this row always be executed and if so, is it a big impact if you have alot of debug logging?
I've seen a few applications that have a property called debug=true and in the code the type

```
if(debug) {
    LOGGER.debug("log message");
}
```

Is this a better approach or should I just continue to use LOGGER.debug() without the proeprty check?

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: refer:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm  Logger request should be >= current level

Comment: I know how to configure the Logger. But the thing is, if I set it to info. will it still process the debug without any output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logging classes are just normal Java classes.

If you have a method call in your code, it will be called.

However… all logging frameworks’ log methods are designed to return immediately if the relevant level is not enabled, which makes the entire method call have so little cost it’s essentially nothing.  For that reason, you almost never should use `if (debug)` or `if (logger.isDebugEnabled())`.  They aren’t saving any time at all.

However, normal Java methods are still normal Java methods.  When you execute this:

```
LOGGER.debug(model.toString());
```

Java will first invoke `model.toString()`, then pass the result of that to the logger.  Unlike the logger call, that toString *can* be expensive, if the toString method does a lot of work and/or is called very frequently.  To address this, logging frameworks have *parameterized* log methods, which will convert arguments to strings only if the relevant level is enabled.

Using java.util.logging.Logger, it looks like this:

```
logger.log(Level.FINE, "Model={0}", model);     // no toString() call
```

Using SLF4J or Log4j:

```
logger.debug("Model={}", model);                 // no toString() call
```

Comment: Thank you!
I should have known that the toString will always be executed. So if there are method calls in the debug there is nothing wrong with adding a
`if(logger.isDebugEnabled())` before it.

Thank you.

Comment: for slf4j, 
    log.debug(String.format("model is %s", model.toString()));
also will avoid toString() execution if log level is info or higher.

Comment: @cjo No, it won’t.  At the moment the method is called, you have already called both toString() and String.format.

Answer (score 1):

This has not so much to do with loggers, but everything with how expressions in Java are evaluated. Contrary to for example Haskell, which does lazy evaluation, all expressions in a parameter list in Java are always evaluated, with the exception of Boolean short-cut.

So, if you do this:

```
LOGGER.debug(model.toString());
```

this is always evaluated, regardless of your logging level. This is why you should always use this form:

```
if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.debug(model.toString());
}
```

The impact of the call to `isDebugEnabled()` is negligible.

The one time that Java stops evaluating is if a Boolean expression is already determined to be `false`, so this will not thrown an exception:

```
if (1 == 0 && 0 / 0 > 0) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: This is a valid comment, I don't see why you get downvoted. Both your answer and the other answer is good. VGR did give a bit more insight though that the toString is always executed.

Comment: No idea either, although I do agree that using more modern techniques as used by slf4j make more sense – if it can all be done using the `toString` method. I took the angle of explaining the reasons why this solution is taken, which is the eager evaluation that Java uses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better approach with lambdas.

```
LOGGER.debug(() -> model.toString())
```

This will ensure that only when the level is set to debug,

> model.toString()

will be evaluated.

Essentially this turns an eager evaluation of

> model.toString()

to lazy evaluation.

There is quite a bit of information on using lambdas for lazy evaluation on the web, so I wont repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

In SLF4J there is no lambda implementation, yet. So you can add your own helper method:

```
public static Object lazy(Callable<?> callable) {
    return new Object() {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            try {
                Object result = callable.call();
                if (result == null) {
                    return "null";
                }

                return result.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And then use like this:

```
LOGGER.debug("Expensive operation: {}", lazy(() -> expensiveOperation()));
```